# NSWindow Animate show / hide titlebar

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nswindow, titlebar

I am able to show and hide my NSWindows titlebar in one of two ways via an action method containing :

```
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
window.movableByWindowBackground  = true
```

or preferably :

```
window.styleMask = NSBorderlessWindowMask
window.movableByWindowBackground  = true
window.canBecomeKeyWindow
```

Am I able to animate this with a fade effect in any way..? Or would that involve a far more convoluted method of showing and hiding the windows titlebar..?

Answer (score 8):

Ok I have found a solution to showing and hiding the NSWindow titlebar with an animated effect.

You could implement this in any method, I have the titlebar fading out on a text changed event method, and fading back in with any movement.

Fade out the titlebar :

```
    if window.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)?.superview?.alphaValue > 0.1 {
        window.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)?.superview?.animator().alphaValue = 0
    }
```

Fade in the titlebar :

```
    if window.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)?.superview?.alphaValue < 1 {
        window.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)?.superview?.animator().alphaValue = 1
    }
```

So we are getting the titlebar view by the fact that it is the superview of the standardWindowButtons. And simply animating the alpha value of the titlebar view.

Answer (score 1):

Gary Simpson's answer refactored.

```
extension NSWindow {

    func setTitleBarHidden(hidden: Bool, animated: Bool = true) {

    let buttonSuperView = standardWindowButtonSuperView()
    if buttonSuperView == nil {
        return
    }
    let view = buttonSuperView!
    if hidden {
        if view.alphaValue > 0.1 {
            if !animated {
                view.alphaValue = 0
                return
            }
            view.animator().alphaValue = 0
        }
        return
    }
    if view.alphaValue < 1 {
        if !animated {
            view.alphaValue = 1
            return
        }
        view.animator().alphaValue = 1
    }
}

func standardWindowButtonSuperView() -> NSView? {
    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/28381918
    return standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)?.superview
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm that in Objective-C this does the trick:

```
[[[_window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] animator] setAlphaValue:0];
[[[_window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton] animator] setAlphaValue:0];
[[[_window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton] animator] setAlphaValue:0];
```